# Is it possible to point DateTimeOffset custom format for object's property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net

Is it possible to point DateTimeOffset custom format for object's property? This object will be serialized/deserialized (JSON) in ASP.NET controller's action.

I thought it can be done through attribute, like `[Required], but I didn't find it.

```
public abstract class EventDto
{
    public EventDto(EventTypes eventType)
    {
        EventType = eventType;
    }

    [Required]
    public EventTypes EventType { get; }

    [Required]
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    // Something like this: [JsonFormat("YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS.FFFFFFFF zzz")]
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What JSON serializer are you using?

Comment: @Llama I use `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`.

Comment: Looks like it's a matter of specifying a custom converter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#registration-sample---jsonconverter-on-a-property - there's even a sample specifically for `DateTimeOffset` at the top of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
       public class Test
        {
            public DateTime date { get; set; } 
            public string Timestamp
            {
                get { return date.ToString("YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS.FFFFFFFF zzz");}
                set { date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS.FFFFFFFF zzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}
            }
        }
```

Comment: But you will need to switch the format's casing (mm=minute, MM=month, it's yyyy for year etc)

Comment: No.  The JSON is a string.  The class object is a DateTime.  The Net methods ToString() and ParseExact() will take care of the conversion.  From c# all you care about is the DateTime object.